# fastest way to compare text file content

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, count

I have a question to help streamline my programming. 
So I have this file `text.txt` and in it I want to look through it and compare it with a list of words `words` and each time the word is found it adds `1` to an integer.

```
words = ['the', 'or', 'and', 'can', 'help', 'it', 'one', 'two']
ints = []
with open('text.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        for part in line.split():
            for word in words:
                if word in part:
                    ints.append(1)
```

I was just wondering if there was a faster way to do this? The text files could be rather larger and the list of words will be much larger.

Comment: Do you want to find the number of matches?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert the `words` to a `set`, so that the lookups will be faster. This should give a good performance boost to your program, because looking up a value in a list has to traverse the list one element at a time (O(n) runtime complexity), but when you convert the list to a set, the runtime complexity will reduce to O(1) (constant time). Because sets use hashes to find the elements.

```
words = {'the', 'or', 'and', 'can', 'help', 'it', 'one', 'two'}
```

And then whenever there is a match, you can use `sum` function to count it like this

```
with open('text.txt') as file:
    print(sum(part in words for line in file for part in line.split()))
```

---

**Boolean values and their integer equivalents**

In Python, the result of boolean expressions will be equal to either `0` or `1` for `False` and `True` respectively.

```
>>> True == 1
True
>>> False == 0
True
>>> int(True)
1
>>> int(False)
0
>>> sum([True, True, True])
3
>>> sum([True, False, True])
2
```

So whenever you check if `part in words`, the result will be either `0` or `1` and we `sum` all those values.

---

The above seen code is functionally equivalent to

```
result = 0
with open('text.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        for part in line.split():
            if part in words:
                 result += 1
```

---

**Note:** In case you really wanted to get `1`'s in a list whenever there is a match, then you can simply convert the generator expression to `sum` to a list comprehension, like this

```
with open('text.txt') as file:
    print([int(part in words) for line in file for part in line.split()])
```

---

**Frequency of words**

If you actually wanted to find the frequency of individual words in the `words`, then you can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) like this

```
from collections import Counter
with open('text.txt') as file:
    c = Counter(part for line in file for part in line.split() if part in words)
```

This will internally count the number of times each of the words in `words` occur in the file.

---

As per [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694928/fastest-way-to-compare-text-file-content/30694973?noredirect=1#comment49448448_30694973), you can have a dictionary where you can store positive words with positive score, and negative words with negative score and count them like this

```
words = {'happy': 1, 'good': 1, 'great': 1, 'no': -1, 'hate': -1}
with open('text.txt') as file:
    print(sum(words.get(part, 0) for line in file for part in line.split()))
```

Here, we use `words.get` dictionary to get the value stored against the word and if the word is not found in the dictionary (neither a good word nor a bad word) then return the default value `0`.

Comment: Thanks for this, I did a `timeit` of all the functions listed here and yours came out the fastest. Also as to why I'm doing `1`'s. I'm comparing articles as to whether they are positive or negative articles. So if there is a positive word it puts a `1`, if negative then `-1`. Then it sums it and shows whether the article has a positive or negative tone. So thanks again!

Comment: @user1985351 Okay, I included a way to solve the actual problem you are trying to solve. Let me know if it helps, otherwise I ll remove it. Also, please include all these information in the question itself. It will help the future readers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `set.intersection` to find the intersection between a set and list so as a more efficient way put your words within a `set` and do :

```
words={'the','or','and','can','help','it','one','two'}
ints=[]
with open('text.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        for _ in range(len(words.intersection(line.split()))):
              ints.append(1)
```

Note that the preceding solution is based on your code that you added 1 to a list. of you want to find the final count you can use a generator expression within `sum` :

```
words={'the','or','and','can','help','it','one','two'}
with open('text.txt') as f:
    sum(len(words.intersection(line.split())) for line in f)
```